# Newlines not appearing where I want them in generated javascript

Tags: javascript

I am sticking values into a script, and I am using the function below to 'implode' the array

```
function implode() { var str='';
    for(item in globvars)
       str +='\n'+globvars[item]+';';
    return str+'\n';
}
```

Sample usage:

```
globvars = ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'];
output = '<script type = "text/javascript">\n'+implode(globvars)+'</script\>';
```

Expected output **should be**:

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    Tom
    Dick
    Harry
    </script>

    Instead, I am getting something like this:

    <script type = "text/javascript">
    Tom Dick Harry </script>
```

what the ... ?

Comment: `{'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'}`? This isn't a correct syntax.

Comment: And your editor uses `\n` as line break sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working allright for me. Are you outputting the `output` to the browser? Browsers ignore newlines etc, do an `alert(output)` and you'll see that the newlines are there.

Also, your current initialization of `globvars` is wrong, you can't build an object like that. Use `[ ]` to build an array:

```
globvars = ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'];
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. I am displaying in browser though

Answer (score 1):

If you make your `globvars` as an array (see Tatu's answer), you can use the internal `.join` instead of `implode`:

```
globvars = ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'];
output = '<script type = "text/javascript">\n'+ globvars.join(";\n") +';\n</script\>';
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tatu Ulmanen

He is rendering a script tag. If he was doing <div>...</div> the \ns will get stripped out.

@OP

Try sending

```
<script><![CDATA[
    x
    y
    z
]]></script>
```

The ajax request might have munged it and stripped the newlines. If this was a straight-up rendering into a regular request the browser should not remove the \ns.

If this does not work please indicate:

What browser is being tested on, what kind of request is done, what you are trying to accomplish such that these newlines are so important.